# Delete record using ListBox and Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I need show all records from database in `ListBox` and add button in `ListBox` to delete that particular record from database using c# in wpf application.
I used... but not able to add `Button` in `ListBox` in front of record.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Content = "myitem";
    b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
    listboxEmployee.Items.Add(b);
}
void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //code
}
```

And XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Name="listboxEmployee" SelectionChanged="listboxEmployee_SelectionChanged"> 
    <ListView.View> 
        <GridView> 
            <GridViewColumn> 
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This should be done in the XAML for your window. Do you need to do it programmatically?

Comment: Post your XAML code. it should be done in your `ListBox`'s `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Name="listboxEmployee" SelectionChanged="listboxEmployee_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View> is it possible using xaml? if yes then please give me solution.
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

Comment: Use the Edit link in your question and update the text there, do not add code in comments, it is unformattable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<GridView>
   <GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Button Name="btnDelete"  Content="Delete" Click="BtnDelete_OnClick" />
           </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

And then:

```
private void BtnDelete_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = (((sender as Button).DataContext) as YourModel).Property;
    //Write Delete code based on "s" value
}
```